# Visual studio 2010 has to close each time to make the changes in the web page to visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010

While using Visual Studio 2010, it has to close every time to make the chagnes visible every time. Anyone here have reason behind this and probable solution for the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you save the file while the application is 'playing' you should be able to just refresh the application and run from the new saved page. You should not have to close the program each time.